# rsync - Why is there an --include-from and an --exclude-from option?

Tags: rsync

The [rsync man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) says that...

**--include-from=FILE:** "specifies a FILE that contains include patterns.."
Likewise that...
**--exclude-from=FILE:** "specifies a FILE that contains exclude patterns.."

But I have also read examples on the internet where the same FILE can contain both patterns to include (if preceded by a +) and patterns to exclude (if preceded by a -)

Example:

```
+ testfile.txt
- testfile*
```

I know that order is important so here, if testfile.txt is matched then it will be copied to a destination dir but testfile[anything else] will not be copied.

If FILE can contain patterns to include and to exclude then why does rsync have both options **--include-from=FILE** and **--exclude-from=FILE**? It seems to me they both do the same thing. It's the order of matches (preceded by a + or a -) that determines if the file is copied or not.

Can someone give me an example of why you would use the --include-from option instead of the --exclude-from option? Can they both be used together? How would you?

Cheers,

Flex

Comment: The difference between the two is how they handle files that are preceded by neither `+` nor `-`.  This makes it possible to use either one with a plain list of files that has not been marked up with `+`/`-` prefixes.

Comment: Cheers. So it seems unnecessary to have both options then. I think having both just causes confusion. Do you know which option FILE rsync works on first, the --include-from or the --exclude-from? Maybe it depends on which option is specified first (from left to right) after the rsync command?

Comment: Having both could be useful.  If I have two lists of files produced by some elaborate procedure, and I want to exclude set A but include set B, this way I can just write `rsync --exclude-from=A --include-from=B ...`.  If they didn't both exist then I'd have to write a separate script to prepend a `-` to everything in file A and a `+` to everything in file B.

Comment: From the man page, it seems that `--include-from` and `--exclude-from` are parsed left to right, along with other `--include`/`--exclude`/`--filter` options, and added to the list of filter rules in that order.  See the "Filter Rules" section of the man page.    For each given file, the first matching rule in the filter rules list is the one that determines what to do.